# What’s the definition of a ‘maximal free submodule’?

Tags: abstract-algebra

**Am I correct:** A maximal free submodule in a module $M$ is a maximal element of the set of all free submodules in $M$, with inclusion as the partial order?

Comment: Yes. Note that maximal free submodules need not always exist since the union of a chain of free modules need not be free - think about $\mathbb{Q}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks. So is my definition correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.